# mechanize opening multiple pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, web-scraping

I am using mechanize and beautifulsoup to create a python script to pull some data from a web page.  The scraping works fine but the problem I am having is in moving to multiple pages.  Is there a way to move between pages in mechanize in a loop?

Here's what I tried

```
Browser().follow_link(text_regex="Next")
```

but it goes to the next page which is fine but if the "Next" button doesn't exist it just dies.  I'm not sure how to either make a better loop or really just check if the link exists before running the above follow link command.

Most of the examples and documentation I have found seems to only work on one page.

Comment: You may wish to post more of your code, it's hard to comment on just one line.. :)

Comment: @sarnold: Did you intentionally leave the `Broswer` typo?

Comment: @phooji, thanks for pointing it out. Character-transposition typos are nearly impossible for me to spot and I assumed the underlining was from the parenthesis. :)

Comment: @sarnold: Thanks for the fix. I wasn't sure if you were taking 'respect the original question' to a new extreme ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your code "just die"? If it throws an exception, you can catch it and do something to handle it propery (inside your loop as is):

```
try:
   Browser.follow_link(text_regex="Next")
except Exception:
   print "No more next button; terminating loop (but not dying mysteriously)"
   break
```

Comment: Thank you so much Phooji.  It worked like a charm.  Sorry for the type and thanks so much for your help.  I spent a day trying to figure this out.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hehe, awesome "(but not dying mysteriously)" :)

Comment: LOL. I'm so nice to python and getting back into programming that everything is one big giant mystery to me.  What better way to learn then read a few books, hack a few scripts together and bug smart people like the people here when I hit a wall :-)